# Ubuntu 14.04 failed LiveUSB boot on Lenovo G580

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, lenovo

So.. hello, everyone.

I have a Lenovo G580 laptop, with 4 GB RAM, Intel Core i3, 2.5GHz and pre-installed Windows 8, which I updated to Windows 8.1 .

I was like "wow, it's be so nice to have Ubuntu on it, aswell", since I'm planning on going to an IT college and I heard it's easier to use for Perl and Python programming. (Yeah, I'm young...) So, getting back to the subject..

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 on the same machine with a Windows 8.1 .
I downloaded the **desktop Ubuntu 14.04 ISO** and "installed" it on a USB 16GB Flash Drive, trying to boot from it, with 'YUMI – Your Universal Multiboot Installer'.
I left 90GB of **unpartitioned** disk space.

I **disabled Secure Boot without disabling UEFI**, then I plugged in the Flash Drive and chose the option so the laptop would boot from **EFI Drive** (which seemed the right one). Here's where the problems start appearing.

If I don't press anything, I only leave the Flash Drive plugged in and I turn on or restart the laptop, it gets stuck at the black loading screen, with the white Lenovo logo. With no real reason.

If I boot from USB Flash Drive **with enabled UEFI**, the laptop restarts all by itself when it reaches the same black loading screen. Again, and again, and again... until I turn the laptop off manually.

If I boot from USB Flash Drive **with enabled Legacy mode**, the laptop gets stuck (again) at the same black loading screen with the Lenovo logo.

I've googled this all day, but it seems there's no topic / tutorial about this problem. (Or I haven't found it? I don't know.)

I'd need some help, since I really want to have Ubuntu installed here.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. Apparently, my computer doesn't even enter the boot mode, it just freezes at a certain point. It doesn't even show any error messages..

Comment: I've been known to be wrong!

Answer (score 0):

I always find it most reliable to use a dvd or cd, your computer doesn't seem to be recognizing the flash drive as a boot volume. Try burning a cd instead.